# use twitter iOS client authorization on own server

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, authentication, twitter, devise

I try to do the same than : [use facebook iOS client authorization on own to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7840422/use-facebook-ios-client-authorization-on-own-to-server), but with twitter.

I use SSO with Twitter Kit (Fabric) on iOS. I manage to sign in and get the authToken and authTokenSecret of the user. Then, I would like to send these to my server, so that I can retrieve the corresponding user in my own database.

I know I have to use a OAuth client. Working with Rails, I use the twitter gem.

But when I try to do :

```
client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key        = "YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY" #I added my rail app at twitter dev center
  config.consumer_secret     = "YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET" #idem
  config.access_token        = "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN" #from the ios app
  config.access_token_secret = "YOUR_ACCESS_SECRET" #from the ios app
end
```

I keep having a 401 Twitter::Error::Unauthorized, Could not authenticate you. And I'm stuck. Did I do something wrong?

Is this because the ios app that fetched the first access tokens is different than the rails app (and so the consumer_key/secret of the rails app won't work)?

Thank you very much

Jery

PS: I have been stuck for several days, so if you have an answer, you will save my week ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question:
The process described in the question works. The only thing that I corrected is the consumer_key and consumer_secret.
Since the access_token/secret of the user were generated by the iOS SSO, the **consumer_key** and **consumer_secret** needed were not the ones of your rails app, but **the one of your iOS app** (that you can find in Fabric admin).

Then, the twitter client in your rails app can send back all relevant information about the user in your database.