# Verify Twitter login from iPhone on the server side

Tags: iphone, ios, authentication, twitter, verification

Ok, so I've currently implemented Facebook login in my app the following way:

I use the official FB framework to login the user. When I login, I get a authentication token, which is sent to my server. I then do another verification of the user (e.g. get "me" from Facebook, using the auth-token), and then return 32 char random key, which is used to identify the user in subsequent API-calls (to my server). [An example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4623974/design-for-facebook-authentication-in-an-ios-app-that-also-accesses-a-secured-we).

I'm trying to figure out how to do the same with twitter, but I can't understand how to get the oath token in iOS? I have the server-side part working in another app, but no token to verify...

Please advice – is this (the FB way) how I should be doing this, or how would you go about the verification process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sean Cook, engineer @ Twitter has a [github repo](https://github.com/seancook/TWReverseAuthExample) with a simple app that do exactly what you are trying to do, I'using this code in my app and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

There's a good article at [dev.twitter.com](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios/using-reverse-auth) describing exactly that. Basically you'll have to first get a special request token by setting the `x_auth_mode` parameter to the value `reverse_aut` and then get the proper access token by sending what you got in the first step as `x_reverse_auth_parameters`.

Answer (score -2):

If you are going for an `iOS 5` solution, you can import this into your header file

```
 #import < Twitter/TWTweetComposeViewController.h >
```

and then in the `.m` file where you want to authenticate

```
if ([TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet])
{

            TWTweetComposeViewController* twc = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
            [twc addImage:uiImage
            [self presentModalViewController:twc animated:YES];
            twc.completionHandler = ^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result) 
            {

                if (result == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultCancelled)
                    NSLog(@"Tweet compostion was canceled.");
                else if (result == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultDone)
                    NSLog(@"Tweet composition completed.");

                // Dismiss it
                [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
            };
            [twc release];
        } else
        {
            //can't tweet

        }
```

You can also add URLs, text and other sorts of information.

Edit: You can find a tutorial on adding the needed Library to your project here, 
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios/how-add-twitter-framework-your-ios-project

Comment: How does this answer the question?