# Android - Show page content after Facebook auth

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

There is a website that uses Facebook auth for Login.

I'm developing an app that fetch data from the website after logging in via facebook.
The problem is that the website also uses facebook auth, and the page i want to connect to has dynamic content (depends on who is the user).

How can i connect to that page? i can talk to the website developer if necessary.

Comment: You might want to implement the authentication logic described in [Design for Facebook authentication in an iOS app that also accesses a secured web service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4623974/design-for-facebook-authentication-in-an-ios-app-that-also-accesses-a-secured-we)

Comment: Thanks! I also thought about it, but i thought there is another way to do this.