# Server-side login with Facebook from iOS native WebView

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication, server-side, facebook-login

I am developing a native iOS app that leverages some web services provided by my backend server. Some services need the authentication of the user and the requirements are that the authentication would be carried out either by a user account created directly on the server, either with Facebook, or with Twitter.

To simplify the things, the creators of the backend server have decided that the server would carry out server-side authentication with FB or Twitter (or of course use its own authentication mechanism if the user chooses to log in with directly with the account on the server), and return me an own access token of the server after the authentication succeeded, independently from which flow (FB/Twitter/own) it followed.

So the current flow of authentication looks like:

- I open a web view from the native iOS app with the URL of the login page. The page has a "Login with FB" and a "Login with Twitter" button, and a small user/pass form for the direct authentication.
- If the user selects "Login with FB", the server redirects the web view to the authentication page of the FB app, where the user should enter his FB credentials. The same thing happens with Twitter.
- The FB/Twitter redirect URL is set directly to the server, so after FB/Twitter successfully authenticates the user, it sends the access token to the server. The server creates a new user session, generates its own access token and sends it to the redirect URL of the native app.
- If the user enters the direct server credentials on the form, the server simple creates the user session, its auth token and sends it to the redirect URL.
- The native app is observing the web view through its delegate, and continuously looks for the predefined redirect URL (something like `http://myserver.com/authentication_success/?authToken=xyz`) If the request passed in `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` matches this pattern, it extracts the authToken and closes the web view.
- The auth token will be passed to each service requests that needs user authentication.

My question is: is this architecture valid and will be accepted by Apple? My concern is that since at a certain point the user might be asked to enter its Facebook credentials on my web view, theoretically I could access his FB password through the delegate. Could it be a reason to reject the app?

I found this doc: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web-no-jssdk/ that speaks about that you might want to use browser-based login for a "login flow using entirely server-side code". Can my case applied to this case?

Comment: Similar/duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4623974/design-for-facebook-authentication-in-an-ios-app-that-also-accesses-a-secured-we

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A follow up to this question: I submitted to the App Store an app with the fb-login architecture outlined above and it was accepted and published.

Comment: Hi @MrTJ,have you made any tutorial to explain the adopted solution? Thanks!