# Is it possible to integrate the Facebook login without using the iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Currently i am using the Facebook SDK to implement the Facebook login to our native iOS application. For this i am using the native iOS SDK for Facebook. This application is both for mobile and web, so is it possible to integrate Facebook login without using the SDK from application side. I mean authentication done fully through API and server side.

Please have a suggestion.

I referred to a SO link:

[Design for Facebook authentication in an iOS app that also accesses a secured web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4623974/design-for-facebook-authentication-in-an-ios-app-that-also-accesses-a-secured-we?rq=1)

Comment: Did you find a good solution? I am just tired of all the stupid things Facebook is doing (seeing crashes all of a sudden now in their SDK) if all I want is the ability for users to login

Answer (score 0):

Sure! You can always use their API directly, which essentially is the same as they do with the SDK.

Check out the documentation on the following link.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow